# Google Cloud Speech service is down?

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

The problem is I am using v1 and the latest @0.10.2. It worked perfectly for 6 months (even v1beta) until yesterday when it just randomly (and silently!) stops working. I mean one call of streamingRecognize may go well and recognition starts, but then second or third call of streamingRecognize just don't receive any input (and I'm getting you're streaming to slow error). Using the same code!

And even in recognition starts, the quality is very low. Often leading to completely wrong results.

The problem started occuring after releasing V1 from beta, I suppose, but I'm not sure.

Environment details

```
OS: amazon linux 4.4.44-39.55.amzn1.x86_64
Node.js version: v7.2.1
npm version: 3.10.10
using google-cloud/speech@0.10.2
```

The code:

```
var Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
credentials: require(_base + '/google_cloud_credential.json')
});
self.recognizeStream = Speech.streamingRecognize({
        config: {
            encoding: 'MULAW',
            sampleRateHertz: 8000,
            languageCode: "ru-RU",
        },
        singleUtterance: false,
        interimResults: true
});

self.iStream.pipe(self.recognizeStream)
.on('error', function(err) {
                logger.error('google-speech error:', err);
                self.restartRecognizing(); //GOOGLE BUG: randomly crashes https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1894
            })
.on('end', function(err) {
                logger.trace('google-speech end:', err);                    
            })                
.on('close', function(err) {
                logger.error('google-speech close: ', err);
                self.restartRecognizing(); //GOOGLE BUG: randomly crashes https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1894
            })                
.on('data', function(data) {
                //logger.warn(data);
                require('tracer').setLevel('info');

                if(data.results && data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives)
                    logger.warn("isFinal: %s,  conf: %s,  stab: %s,  trans: %s,  delay=%s", data.results[0].isFinal, data.results[0].alternatives[0].confidence, data.results[0].stability, data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript, Number(self.thisDate-self.prevDate));

                if(!self.isListeningEmitted && data && data.results && data.results[0] && !data.results[0].isFinal)
                {
                    self.isListeningEmitted = true;
                    self.emit('started_hearing_speech');
                }
                if(data && data.results && data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives && !data.results[0].isFinal)
                {                        
                    self.thisDate = Date.now();
                    if(!self.prevDate)
                        self.prevDate = self.thisDate;

                    logger.debug("isFinal: %s,  conf: %s,  stab: %s,  trans: %s,  delay=%s", data.results[0].isFinal, data.results[0].alternatives[0].confidence, data.results[0].stability, data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript, Number(self.thisDate-self.prevDate));
                    self.prevDate = self.thisDate;

                    if(self.timer)
                        clearTimeout(self.timer);

                    if(!self.isFired)
                        self.timer = setTimeout(self.onRecognizedText.bind(self), 800, data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);                        
                }
            });
```

And also there are a lot of errors in my Google Cloud Console:
[30 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJxjk.jpg)

Also posted here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2541